# Google Sheets Replace REGEXMATCH with REGEXEXTRACT

Tags: google-sheets, regex

I am working with a Google Sheet where column A contains a set of values.  Every value contains the following string "SAME_WORD LETTER", where LETTER is one of the alphabet letters, like "SAME_WORD A", "SAME_WORD B", "SAME_WORD C", etc.  The first letter in SAME_WORD is always capital, the string may be preceded and followed by either a space or a symbol (like a dash) but never by another letter or number.

The following formula does what I need for A, B, and C but it's very long with all the alphabet letters

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"\b SAME_WORD A(.*)"),"SAME_WORD A",IF(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"\b SAME_WORD B(.*)"),"SAME_WORD B",IF(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"\b SAME_WORD C(.*)"),"SAME_WORD C"))))
```

I would like to improve efficiency and learn something so my request is to modify my formula to remove the conditionals and use something else instead, like REGEXEXTRACT.

TIA

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexextract()` like this:

`=arrayformula( iferror( regexextract(A1:A, "(?:\b|\s)(SAME_WORD [A-Z])") ) )`

To learn the exact [regular expression](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).